# Adobe Air and Serial Port Communication with Serproxy/Thinkerproxy

Tags: air, serial-port

I'm using serproxy / thinkerproxy for serial communication in a small Air app.
I have two hardware devices to test it. One is a barcode scanner, it works perfectly.

The other is a custom board. It's kind of working also. The problem is that the characters are unreadable. I think it's a problem of charset (not sure) so I tried something like this in the function that handles the ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA event:

```
var cs:Array = new Array(   'ISO-8859-1',
                                            'ISO-8859-2',
                                            'ISO-8859-3',
                                            'ISO-8859-4',
                                            'ISO-8859-5',
                                            'ISO-8859-6',
                                            'ISO-8859-7',
                                            'ISO-8859-8',
                                            'ISO-8859-9',
                                            'ISO-8859-10',
                                            'ISO-8859-11',
                                            'ISO-8859-12',
                                            'ISO-8859-13',
                                            'ISO-8859-14',
                                            'ISO-8859-15',
                                            'ISO-8859-16',
                                            'ISO-8859-17',
                                            'ISO-8859-18',
                                            'ISO-8859-19',
                                            'ISO-8859-20',
                                            'ASMO-708',
                                            'DOS-720',
                                            'x-mac-arabic',
                                            'windows-1256',
                                            'ibm775',
                                            'windows-1257',
                                            'ibm852',
                                            'x-mac-ce',
                                            'windows-1250',
                                            'gb18030',
                                            'EUC-CN',
                                            'gb2312',
                                            'gb18030',
                                            'hz-gb-2312',
                                            'x-mac-chinesesimp',
                                            'big5',
                                            'x-Chinese-CNS',
                                            'x-Chinese-Eten',
                                            'x-mac-chinesetrad',
                                            'cp866',
                                            'koi8-r',
                                            'koi8-u',
                                            'x-mac-greek',
                                            'windows-1253',
                                            'ibm869',
                                            'DOS-862',
                                            'iso-8859-8-i',
                                            'x-mac-hebrew',
                                            'windows-1255',
                                            'x-EBCDIC-Arabic',
                                            'x-EBCDIC-CyrillicRussian',
                                            'x-EBCDIC-CyrillicSerbianBulgarian',
                                            'x-EBCDIC-DenmarkNorway',
                                            'x-ebcdic-denmarknorway-euro',
                                            'x-EBCDIC-FinlandSweden',
                                            'x-ebcdic-finlandsweden-euro',
                                            'x-ebcdic-finlandsweden-euro',
                                            'x-iscii-as',
                                            'unicode',
                                            'unicodeFFFE',
                                            'utf-7',
                                            'utf-8',
                                            'us-ascii',
                                            'windows-1258',
                                            'x-IA5',
                                            'Windows-1252'
                                        );

                for each(var csStr:String in cs){

                    var info:String = _socket.readMultiByte(_socket.bytesAvailable, csStr);
                    temp = csStr + ":" + info;

                    if(info.length > 0)
                        dispatchEvent(new TextEvent(EVENT_ON_DATA_RECEIVED, false, false, temp) );
                }
```

The only value that contains a value is **ISO-8859-1**. and and it looks like this:[image]

The custom board is supposed to send something like : **0x40**

So, not sure what is the best approach here (I know there are more charset I can try). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to guess unknown encoding? Look at raw bytes that board sends to check whether they are bit-shifted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your settings - I'd suspect differing settings for parity bit.